# Extracting browser from user_agent from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, user-agent

I need to extract the browser name from a list of user_agents, which is stored as a column in a dataframe.

I want to use the Python library user_agents (https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/), but I can't figure out how to apply the command `user_agent.browser.family` on my dataframe columns.

So if df_user_agent['context_user_agent'] is the column with the user_agents, and I want to populate df_user_agent['browser'] with the outputs of `user_agent.browser.family`, what code should I use? Everything I've tried results in errors.

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible example so we can try to solve it !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.